# Can I access to index of Object in ng-options

Tags: angularjs, ng-options

I use ng-options for show data in array of object.

index.html

```
<select ng-model="object_choose" 
ng-options="values.id as values.label for values in array_object">
</select>
<button ng-click="get_my_array()">Get Array</button>
```

controller.js

```
app.controller('Ctrl', function ($scope) {

$scope.array_object = [
    {"id": "a", "label": "A", "my_array": [1, 2, 3, 4]},
    {"id": "b", "label": "B", "my_array": [1, 4, 8]},
    {"id": "c", "label": "C", "my_array": [2,6]}
];

$scope.get_my_array = (function() {
      console.log($scope.object_choose); //It work and show "id" a , b , c
      console.log($scope.object_choose.my_array); //It not work
  });  

});
```

Can I get array in Object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way would be to store the real value in your model with:

```
ng-options="values as values.label for values in array_object"
```

You can then access this as follows:

```
console.log($scope.object_choose.id);       // a , b , c
console.log($scope.object_choose.my_array); // the array
```

The trick is to understand the many ways you can write the expression to manipulate how data a stored and displayed. The [manual](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions) has all the info you need.

Comment: A little faster than me, but that's definitely the good answer. Adding just a little explanation about which part of the ng-options is stored in the model would help some people in my opinion.

Comment: @Okazari Mere seconds ;) // Regarding an better explanation, I'll add a link to the manual, it's far more exaustive as could/should be put here.